# working with pointers and linkedLists: how to iterate over a linked list, change and compare keys

Tags: algorithm, pointers, linked-list, pseudocode

I am asked to implement an algorithm based upon the data structure of a `linkedList` in the form of pseudocode.

Unfortunately I have a Python/Java background and thus no experience with pointers.

Could someone explain me how I would iterate over a `doublyLinkedList`, change and compare values of elements.

From what I have understood so far, i would do something like this.: to have an iteration over each element.

```
for L.head to L.tail
```

But how would I then access the current object in the list analogous to `A[i] for i to L.length`?

As the `order of a linkedList is determined by pointers rather than indices in a linkedList` can I simply do things like `currentObj.prev.key = someVal` or `currentObj.key < currentObj.prev.key` or is there some other wokflow to work with individual elements?

Again, I am obviously stuck as I lack an basic understanding on how to deal with pointers.

Cheers,
Andrew

Answer (score 2):

So basically the data structures are:

- Node:

  ```
  node {
    node next;//"single link"
    node prev;//for "doubly"...
  }
  ```
- and List:

  ```
  list {
     node head;//for singly linked, this'd be enough
     node tail;//..for "doubly" you "point" also to "tail"
     int/*long*/ size; //can be of practical use
  }
  ```

The (common) operations of a list:

- Creation/Initialization:

  ```
  list:list() {
      head = null;
      tail = null;
      size = 0;
  }
  ```
- Add a node at the first position:

  ```
  void:addFirst(node) {
     if(isEmpty()) {
       head = node;
       tail = node;
       size = 1;
     } else {
       head.prev = node;
       node.next = head;
       head = node;
       size++;
     }
  }
  // ..."add last" is quite analogous...
  ```
- "is empty", can be implemented in different ways..as long as you keep the invariant

  ```
  bool:isEmpty() {
      return size==0;
      //or return head==null ... or tail==null
  }
  ```
- "add a node at position i":

  ```
  void:add(i, node) {
      assert(i>=0 && i <=size);//!
      if(isEmpty() || i == 0) { 
          addFirst(node);
      } else if (i == size) {
          addLast(node);
      } else {//here we could decide, whether i is closer to head or tail, but for simplicity, we iterate "from head to tail".
        int j = 1;
        node cur = head.next; //<- a "cursor" node, we insert "before" it ;) 
        while(j < i) {//1 .. i-1 
           cur = cur.next;// move the cursor
           j++;//count
        }
        //j == i, cur.next is not null, curr.prev is not null, cur is the node at currently i/j position
        node.prev = cur.prev;
        cur.prev.next = node;
        cur.prev = node;
        node.next = cur;
     }
     //don't forget the size:
     size++;
  }
  ```
- Delete(node) is easy!
- "Delete at position", "find node", "get node by position", etc. should use a similar loop (as `add(i, node)`)...to find the correct index or node.

The strength/advantage of a doubly (comparing to a singly) linked list, is that it can iterate as "forth" as "back". To use this advantage (it is only advantageous on index-based operations, for "find(node)" e.g. you still don't know where to start/iterate best), you determine whether `pos` is closer to head(0) or to tail(size-1), and start&route your iteration accordingly.

...What else operations are you intereseted in (detail)?

Comment: ..and "speaking Java": A pointer is a reference to an object.

Comment: Ooh. I was probably not clear about this point. I don't have to come up with a data structure based upon a linkedList. All I need to know is how I would actually "use" a linkedList generally speaking